# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window — token null is not valid

Tags: java, android

I get this error whenever I try to start my window class. I am using separate class, and not just a method within my game class, cause I need to disable back button on that popup window. I am calling this class with a button. This code works fine if I use it within my game class, but not in separate class. Here is my code:

```
public class Popup_pogresno extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private PopupWindow pwindow;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
         = (LayoutInflater)Popup_pogresno.this
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                 pwindow  = new PopupWindow(popupView, 300, 170, true);

                 Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.bPopupOK);
                 btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

         public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             pwindow.dismiss();
         }});

                 pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

       }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not calling `setContentView(R.layout.myLayout)` in your `onCreate(Bundle)` method. Call it right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

This is from the Activity resource page on Android developers site:

> There are two methods almost all subclasses of Activity will
>   implement:
>
> onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a
>   layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to
>   retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with
>   programmatically.
>
> onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving your activity. Most importantly, any changes made by the user should at this point be
>   committed (usually to the ContentProvider holding the data).

**Edit 1:**

Replace:

```
pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```

with:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }

}, 100L);
```

Comment: This is the line of error: pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Comment: It's not an error to omit a call to `setContentView`. The Activity will just have an empty view in that case. That's not usually useful, but it also won't prevent a popup window from displaying.

Comment: @vikram. Yes, it works now. Sort of. I don't get error any more, and I see the popup, but I don't see main activity in the background, I see white plain screen.

Comment: @marjanbaz yes, that's because you probably aren't setting any layout for your activity(or setting an empty layout). I highly recommend you do that. But in any case, what would you like to display behind the popup?

Comment: Well, my game activity. This is my popup for wrong answer. After a user press OK, he should go back to the game.

Comment: @marjanbaz Then you should have this popup inside Game Activity. Simply take the code `LayoutInflater layoutInflater....` onwards and until `pwindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);` and place it in a method inside Game Activity. Call this method whenever you need to show this popup. The code above defines a separate activity.

Comment: I know it works fine like that, I tried it. But I did not manage to disable back burron when in game activity. If I use @override back press, I will disable back button for the whole game activity. Also, I was trying to start an Intent for result, because I need to add one negative point every time user press OK button in this popup. And after 3 points to close game activity. If I do that in my game activity, it will close while popup still opened. Those are the reasons why I tried this approach.

Comment: @marjanbaz I understand. But you have to override back press and inside it, design navigation. This is very important. An example: in your overridden back press --> you will check if the popup is showing, and if it is you will call `pwindow.dismiss()`. You will have to perform these checks for as many views as required. And don't think that you `will disable back button for the whole game activity`, since a call to `return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);` can be made. You can (and probably should) also dismiss your popup in `onPause()` since it is called before `onDestroy()`.